# Gitlab - Can not pull from remote after merge requests accepted

Tags: git, gitlab

I used `git clone git@gitlab.com:user/project.git --branch master --single-branch` to select master branch only.

Cloning was successful. I checked out 2 branches: `b_1` from master and `b_2` from `b_1`. Then I made changes on `b_2`, committed, pushed both `b_1` and `b_2` to origin. After creating Merge Request (MR) from `b_2` into `b_1`, I accepted the MR. Gitlab website said MR was merged.

Then I `git pull` on my PC, but it said `Already up-to-date`. `git fetch --all` did nothing.
The workflow was fine if I `git clone git@gitlab.com:user/project.git` from the beginning.

Here's my terminal log in failed case:

`╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/
╰─$ git clone git@gitlab.com:user/project.git --branch master --single-branch
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Counting objects: 657, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (364/364), done.
remote: Total 657 (delta 274), reused 633 (delta 255)
Receiving objects: 100% (657/657), 152.86 KiB | 196.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (274/274), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/
╰─$ cd project 
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹master› 
╰─$ git checkout -b htl
Switched to a new branch 'htl'
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl› 
╰─$ git push origin -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create merge request for htl:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/user/project/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=htl
remote: 
To git@gitlab.com:user/project.git
 + 9a1e13c...9463f53 htl -> htl (forced update)
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl› 
╰─$ git checkout -b htl_test_mr
Switched to a new branch 'htl_test_mr'
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl_test_mr› 
╰─$ touch test
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl_test_mr*› 
╰─$ git add test 
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl_test_mr*› 
╰─$ git commit -m 'add test file'
[htl_test_mr 0aa06d1] add test file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl_test_mr› 
╰─$ git push origin htl_test_mr
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 270 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create merge request for htl_test_mr:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/user/project/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=htl_test_mr
remote: 
To git@gitlab.com:user/project.git
 * [new branch]      htl_test_mr -> htl_test_mr
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl_test_mr› 
╰─$ git checkout htl
Switched to branch 'htl'
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl› 
╰─$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl› 
╰─$ git pull

Already up-to-date.
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl› 
╰─$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
╭─htl@htl-asus  ~/Desktop/project  ‹htl› 
╰─$`

Please help me resolve this because I don't want to clone all of the repo to my PC.

Thanks a lot!